# PHP script applied to multiple cells

Tags: php, sql

Total beginner.
The Following script is applied to a single cell

```
$sql="UPDATE bdam_eshop_productoptionvalues SET quantity=0 WHERE sku='FR1640' ";
```

it works.

when I tried to apply it to multiple cells like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE bdam_eshop_productoptionvalues SET quantity=1 WHERE sku='FR1640', sku='FR1645'  ";
```

It failed with this error:

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ' sku='FR1645'' at line 1

How do I tell the script to SET quantity=1 to multiple cells?
I want to apply that script to approximately 40 cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 'IN' for the query in question. This allows multiple values to be checked.

The updated query will be

```
UPDATE bdam_eshop_productoptionvalues SET quantity=1 WHERE sku IN ('FR1640', 'FR1645');
```

Also I would recommend reading on prepared statements in order to not open yourself to SQL injection attacks (I assume you are using MySQL).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```
 $sql="UPDATE bdam_eshop_productoptionvalues SET quantity=1 WHERE sku='FR1640' or sku='FR1645' ";
```

Method 2

```
 $sql="UPDATE bdam_eshop_productoptionvalues SET quantity=1 WHERE sku in ('FR1640', 'FR1645')";
```